# Make Directory writable by PHP

Tags: php, apache, chmod

I'm installing a php service on my local host. In installation instructions mentioned that:

> Make application/cache/Twig writable by php.

So i changed ownership and group of the Twig directory to apache and gave write permission to group with:

```
sudo chmod g+w Twig
```

but it still cant write to Twig directory. here is apache log:

> [Mon Jan 25 00:53:11.727898 2016] [:error] [pid 10856] [client 192.168.1.103:56528] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'Unable to create the cache directory (/var/www/html/judge/application/cache/Twig/e4/da).' in /var/www/html/judge/application/third_party/Twig/lib/Twig/Environment.php:1236\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/html/judge/application/third_party/Twig/lib/Twig/Environment.php(334): Twig_Environment->writeCacheFile('/var/www/html/j...', 'loadTemplate('pages/admin/ins...')\n#2 /var/www/html/judge/application/controllers/Install.php(276): Twig->display('pages/admin/ins...', Array)\n#3 [internal function]: Install->index()\n#4 /var/www/html/judge/system/core/CodeIgniter.php(356): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)\n#5 /var/www/html/judge/index.php(285): require_once('/var/www/html/j...')\n#6 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/html/judge/application/third_party/Twig/lib/Twig/Environment.php on line 1236

Also i gave 777 permission to it but unfortunately nothing changed.

Comment: /var/www/html/judge/application/cache/Twig is 777 ?

Comment: @Dagon yes, I chmod it to 777.

Comment: What is the exit of the command namei -m /home/user/dir/child/file?

Comment: @JoaoVitorino you mean /var/www/html/judge/application/cache/Twig?  
Iv attached it here: http://pastebin.com/X7uuTNNv